# What files I need to check-in after adding a web service reference?

Tags: wcf, web-services, version-control

I have a (new) project and it has a web service reference. It has following structure:

```
<Folder: project folder>
    <File: source file 1>
    <File: source file 2>
    <File: source file .>
    Folder: Web References
        Folder: MyService
            File: Reference.map
            File: Reference.cs
            File: MyService.xsd
            File: MyService0.xsd
            File: MyService.wsdl
            File: MyService0.wsdl
            File: MyService0.disco
```

I am about to check-in the source code to version control system. Which files I must check-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of them.

Comment: I don't think this is correct - certainly you don't need the `xsd` files.

Comment: Given that there are conflicting statements around, do you have anything to back up this answer?

Answer (score 7):

Just to add differing opinion in case someone is in similar situation as mine.

I worked on a project where we aggressively developed a web service API, and we used Perforce as our source control. This caused numerous issues when updating service references, which we did many times a day. We simplified this process by checking in only two files:

```
Reference.cs
```

As it contains all the generated compiled code, and:

```
Reference.svcmap
```

As it contains configuration for code generation, such as endpoint used to refresh reference, type of collection to be used,etc.

All the other files as far as I can tell are just artifacts created during code generation that have no effect on executable code.

Answer (score 0):

In TFS we only check in the following 2 files:

- The service .wsdl file
- The Reference.cs file